# Round to sensible location in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to round my floats to get rid of all trailing zeros after the decimal place in rails, inside a model method.

So, `30.0` becomes `30` but `10.5` stays `10.5`.

I know about number_with_precision and it works if I do

```
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

in my model. Is this poor design? Is there a better alternative that doesn't involve moving the rounding into a helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code of the `number_with_precision` method.

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 199
def number_with_delimiter(number, options = {})
  options.symbolize_keys!

  begin
    Float(number)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    if options[:raise]
      raise InvalidNumberError, number
    else
      return number
    end
  end

  defaults = I18n.translate(:'number.format', :locale => options[:locale], :default => {})
  options = options.reverse_merge(defaults)

  parts = number.to_s.to_str.split('.')
  parts[0].gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{options[:delimiter]}")
  parts.join(options[:separator]).html_safe

end
```

Nothing prevents you to clone this method into your model. You might want to remove the unnecessary parts.

Comment: I think you mean: https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L248 . It can't be better to copy paste that in than to just do the include I'm already doing, can it?

Comment: If you include NumberHelper you'll get several other helpers you don't need.